# Changing the name on this Ruby class causes an error

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, yield

I have the following code and it runs as it should:

```
class Array
  def my_name
    first_name = "Bob"
    last_name = "Smith"
    yield(first_name, last_name)
  end
end

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].my_name {|i, x| puts "#{i} #{x}"}
```

But the moment I change the class name from "Array" to something else, say "Array1", I get the following error:

```
`<main>': undefined method `my_name' for ["a", "b", "c", "d"]:Array                              (NoMethodError)
```

I'm not sure what that error means but its breaking my code.  This is the broken code:

```
class Array1
  def my_name
    first_name = "Bob"
    last_name = "Smith"
    yield(first_name, last_name)
  end
end

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].my_name {|i, x| puts "#{i} #{x}"}
```

For the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong.  I'm really just trying to figure out how to use the yield function on methods within a class. I'm really having trouble with that and if someone could help me it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: BTW - `yield` is not a function, but a keyword (i.e. same status as `def` or `end`, not the same status as e.g. `puts`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` is an instance of class `Array` (not of `Array1` class). To be able to call methods defined in class `Array1` you should first create an instance of that class.

```
Array1.new.my_name {|i, x| puts "#{i} #{x}"}
# Bob Smith
#=> nil
```

Comment: Subclassing arrays is a bad, bad idea. Doubly so if it's done just to add a method.

Comment: But I guess here's where I'm confused. I put the two classes I specified earlier in separate files.  Shouldn't they run individually?  Why is ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] and instance of Array if Array doesn't even exist in my .rb file?

Comment: @John123 Array is a core class. You always have access to it and its methods.

Comment: Why for God’s sake anybody would subclass `Array` here? What specific `Array` behaviour is required to call a method `my_name`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I never said it was good idea to subclass an Array. OP asked what is the problem with renaming the core class - I answered. He asked how to make it work - I showed. You're right that it is not needed to subclass an Array.

Answer (score 3):

For unknown reason you are trying to call the newly introduced method on the `Array` instance. Just call it where it belongs:

```
Array1.new.my_name { |i, x| puts "#{i} #{x}" }
```